# Как уменьшить размер текста если он не влезает в TextView?

Tags: xml, android

Есть TextView, который отображает различные небольшие тексты, поэтому шрифт тут крупный и выставлен атрибут android:singleLine="true". Но иногда TextView показывает тексты чуть подлиннее и в его конце текст обрывается и ставится многоточие(из-за singleLine). Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы текст отображался всё-таки полностью, но более мелким шрифтом? Программно можно ли как-то узнать, влез ли текст полностью, или скрывается за многоточием?

на всякий случай, мой TextView:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/mytw"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:text=""
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: попробуй эту библиотеку https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри какая максимальная длина влезающая в `TextView` и просто делай проверку, если она меньше то не меня, в противном случае измени..это конечно грубый метод..

Comment: На разных устройствах по-разному, где-то влезает одна длина, где-то другая... Хотя можно прописать несколько значений, которые бы подставлялись для разных экранов, но я всё же надеялся, что есть более элегантный способ.

Comment: Учитывая что ширина буквенных символов разная, то тут не угадаешь по количеству букв которые влезут в одно и то же пространство. Например: "шжщыю" будет явно занимать больше места нежели "рукть".

Answer (score 1):

Установи `textsize` в `sp`, ну и наверно попробуй вариант @`sulo`. Хотя это реально какой-то костыль.

Answer (score 1):

Или сделать анимацию прокрутки(marquee эффект) длинного текста стандартными способами:

```
<TextView
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Ну или уменьшить размер шрифта для текста.