# TextView показывает не весь текст

Tags: android

TextView показывает не весь текст. Сам текст в строке, состоит из 2000 символов. TextView показывает примерно половину текста, остальную половину обрезает.

Comment: в смысле на экран не влазит? в ScrollView тогда нужно ложить.

Comment: он в нём стоит. немного перематывается и видно, что обрезан текст

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поможет мой ответ тут: [Как уменьшить размер текста если он не влезает в TextView?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/171739#172294)
(Прокрутка длинного текста)

Также стоит поиграться с параметрами TextView: maxLength, textSize.

Answer (score 0):

- 1.Может быть Вам нужен ScrollView?
- 2.TextView должен содержать атрибуты с этими значениями -

> android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

- 3.maxLength - установлен на определенный порог, длину текста.

Вообще, в подобном случае, нужно выкладывать исходники.